# Setting LANDSCAPE orientation when printing

Tags: java, printing, orientation, awt

I need to print an image. When I set orientation like

`printRequestAttributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);`

all works fine.

But when I set orientation inside `print()` method of `Printable`:

```
public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            if (pageIndex >= images.size()) 
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            image = images.get(pageIndex);
            // if image width>height --> Landscape, else --> Protrait
            if (image.getWidth(null) > image.getHeight(null)) 
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            else 
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

            graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null),   null);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
};
```

**it doesn't work with first page. i.e. it prints all pages in Landscape mode except 1-st page.**

Comment: Duplicated question. Look at [Page printing help on first page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495800/page-printing-help-on-first-page)

Comment: `....
      pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);`  What code is in the `....` part?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson code is simple. See updated answer

Comment: You can not change the orientation when your already trying to print the page. If you need to provide a number of pages with different orientations, you will want to look at the [Book](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) [Pageable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Pageable.html) interfaces, see [Printing in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) for examples

Comment: You can pass `PageFormat` argument into `setPrintable` method of `PrinterJob` class. So it will be initialized before printing.

Comment: @cubanacan and it will print ALL pages (inside Printable) in certain format?

Comment: @MyTitle yes, look at answer I have just posted on [Page printing help on first page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495800/page-printing-help-on-first-page/12193974#12193974)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i.e. I need create `Book` object, and add to it as many `Printable` objects as I need? For example I need to print _page1_ in `Landscape` mode, _page2_ in `Portrait`, _page3_ again in `Landscape` and so on.. So I need to create 3 Printable objects, and set to first `PageFormat` with `Landscape` orientation, to second with `Portrait`, to third again with `Landscape` and so on? and then add 3 `Printable` objects to book, and create `new SimpleDoc(book, flavor, attr)`?

Comment: @MyTitle that or rotate the images in the printable ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ok..not good... b.t.w. thanks for your help from day to day. Write first comment as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change the orientation when your already trying to print the page.

If you need to provide a number of pages with different orientations, you will want to look at the [Book](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) and [Pageable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/Pageable.html) interfaces, see [Printing in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1201-print.html) for examples.

The only other solution you have is to rotate the image in `Printable`, which is troublesome at best.

ps - Printing is fun...when it works ;)

Comment: Sorry for being late, but I decide to use your solution. So I have a question: `Book` and `Pageable` interfaces are interchangeable? i.e. if I use Book then I don't need to use `Pageable`?

Comment: Well, `Book` implements `Pagable`. So you could create a `Book` and pass it to methods that were expected `Pagable`, but not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Place `pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE)` before calling `printJob`

ex.

```
if(pay_type.getSelectedItem().equals("EMI"))
  {
      EMI();
  }
  else{
       validation();  
  }
   PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable((Printable) this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
             //here set page oriatetion
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {
          /* The job did not successfully complete */
         }
     }
```