# How can we change the default page setting of print window in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, printing

like the default page orientation(as in images) of print window is Portrait. So how can we change that thing to landscape so when ever we print that page it comes in Landscape orientation. Is there any way to do that.[Default view of print windows in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDn26.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java print API you can set the page orientation as beloe

```
pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE)
```

Also this [Stackoverflow thread may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192656/setting-landscape-orientation-when-printing)

Comment: Can you try using css media to set to landscape?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html